# Linux - AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint touchpad treated as mouse on HP zBook Studio G4

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, touchpad, cinnamon

I'm having issues with the 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint' (HP zBook Studio G4). It is working but is treated as a mouse device, effectively resulting in all the settings I make in 'Mouse and Touchpad' > 'Touchpad' being ignored. E.g. I can disable 'Tap to click' but with no effect. I can even disable 'Enable touchpad' and it will still work.

These are the relevant lines from the Xorg log file:

```
[     9.584] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint (/dev/input/event6)
[     9.584] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[     9.584] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
[     9.584] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[     9.584] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[     9.584] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[     9.584] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: Applying InputClass "libinput touchscreen catchall"
[     9.584] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint'
[     9.584] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: always reports core events
[     9.585] (II) input device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad Touchscreen
[     9.585] (II) input device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint', /dev/input/event6 is a touchpad
[     9.616] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 17)
[     9.616] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[     9.616] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     9.616] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     9.616] (II) input device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad Touchscreen
[     9.616] (II) input device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint', /dev/input/event6 is a touchpad
[     9.616] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint (/dev/input/mouse1)
[     9.616] (**) AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
```

This is the output of 'xinput':

```
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                       id=2   [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ALP0012:00 044E:120C                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Generic USB Audio                          id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse         id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                   id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                      id=3   [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                id=5   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                               id=6   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                  id=7   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                               id=8   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera                 id=9   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard                             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard                             id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sennheiser Sennheiser SC60 for Lync        id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard               id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                        id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                             id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Generic USB Audio                          id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I've manually disabled tapping as follows (but still no effect):

`enter code here`xinput set-prop 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint' 'libinput Tapping Enabled' 0

-->

```
$ xinput --watch-props 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint'
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint':
   Device Enabled (142):   1
   Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144):   1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
   libinput Tapping Enabled (296):   0
   libinput Tapping Enabled Default (297):   0
   libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (298):   1
   libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (299):   1
   libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (300):   0
   libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (301):   0
   libinput Accel Speed (279):   0.996016
   libinput Accel Speed Default (280):   0.000000
   libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (284):   1
   libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (285):   0
   libinput Send Events Modes Available (263):   1, 1
   libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (264):   0, 0
   libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (265):   0, 0
   libinput Left Handed Enabled (286):   0
   libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (287):   0
   libinput Scroll Methods Available (288):   1, 1, 0
   libinput Scroll Method Enabled (289):   1, 0, 0
   libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (290):   1, 0, 0
   libinput Click Methods Available (302):   1, 1
   libinput Click Method Enabled (303):   1, 0
   libinput Click Method Enabled Default (304):   1, 0
   libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (293):   0
   libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (294):   0
   libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (305):   1
   libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (306):   1
   Device Node (266):   "/dev/input/event6"
   Device Product ID (267):   2, 8
   libinput Drag Lock Buttons (295):   <no items>
   libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (268):   0
```

Any hints on how to get this thing working as an actual touchpad would be much appreciated! :)

EDIT: This is not a specific Mint issue - I tested with latest Fedora and it is the same problem there (I hoped that a newer libinput/gtk/whatever version would probably solve the issue).

EDIT 2: Doesn't work on KDE/Kubuntu w/ latest Plasma either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue. Fixed it by doing:

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse`

Answer found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/625064